# Adding Custom attribute to Quote magento 2

Tags: attributes, magento-enterprise, custom-attributes, magento2.4.4, magento-checkout

I need to set a custom attribute to Quote entity. I saw some tutorials on how to set a custom attribute to quote_item, followed a similar structure, but it didn’t work.

I'm on Magento 2.4.4

Here is where i set the attribute:

```
        $quoteSetup = $this->quoteSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $quoteSetup->addAttribute('customer_hit_authnet_profile_limit', 'boolean', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Authnet over profile limit',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'sort_order' => 83,
            'source' => '',
            'global' => 1,
            'visible_on_front' => 1,
            'group' => 'quote',
            'visible' => 1,
            'required' => 0,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'default' => 0,
            'backend' => '',
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
```

Here is where I try to set it.

```
        if ($subject->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($subject->getQuoteId());
        $quote->setCustomAttribute('customer_hit_authnet_profile_limit', '1');
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
        return;
        }
```

I would really apreciate if any of you could help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this according to me by creating event and observer. I have some findings just you need to do minor changes.
Please refer :
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-add-custom-attributes-in-quote-and-order/td-p/477189
Might be helpful for you.
If it is so let me know, and revert back on this post.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($subject->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($subject->getQuoteId());
    $quote->setCustomerHitAuthnetProfileLimit(1);
    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
    return;
    }
```

Can you try above code.